# Method for finding all eigenvalues of a sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I am currently trying to use the sparse matrices from the scipy library to compute all the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix. From what I have seen so far, there is no simple method to get all the eigenvalues of the matrix, but instead a subrange of eigenvalues.
I was wondering whether there is a  method for this somewhere, or perhaps the only way is to compute the eigenvalues in parts and save to an array. **EDIT:** According to this API, [scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh)
, it is not possible to compute all the eigenvalues.

Without the sparse matrices, I am able to code this in numpy, but have a memory allocation error very quickly. I should mention that my matrices have only 5 non-zero entries in a row.

Does anyone know of a method to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you think the sparse functions only return a subrange?  Is there a good computational reason, or are they just lazy or mean?  Does the total number depend on matrix size or the sparsity?

Comment: @hpaulj I've added in the body of the post the API I have found on this method. It says only that the number of eigenvalues should be smaller than N-1, where I think N is the matrix size.

Comment: The sparse eigh uses the implicitly restarted Lanczos Method to find k eigenvalues, and k < n is a requirement in order to make it numerically stable. The dense eigh call uses a different algorithm.